# How can I add customer specific price for configurable and group product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, grouped-products, customer-group

ITEMS group 1 group 2

10ml $3.00 $2.92

20ml $4.25 $4.14

35ml $6.50 $6.33

40ml $10.00 $9.75

for proper format please see http://snag.gy/qBL5Q.jpg

I have configurable products in different bottle size, I want to set price for different customer group as per attached screenshot.

quick help please

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

Put every customer in its own customer group and use the customer group price

Alternative: Use cart/salesrules

Comment: Not working. I tried but no luck

Comment: Please describe in detail what you have tried, what you expected and what didn't work - and DON'T do this in a comment but edit your question!

Comment: I solved issue by adding % difference for associated option of configurable product.